# In activiti business rule task java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/runtime/rule/AgendaFilter

Tags: drools, activiti, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process

In activiti business rule task while deploying I'm getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/runtime/rule/AgendaFilter
```

I've added the jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder and then I deployed the .bar file but then also i'm getting this error for activiti-explorer.

In wso2 bps also I deployed the jar file in repository/components/lib directory and after restarting I deployed the .bar file same exception I got.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have Drools in the classpath, can you see any drools jar inside the WEB-INF/lib directory? It sounds like that is the only thing missing if you are getting that exception.

Comment: Yeah the above exception problem solved. But now I'm getting org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: deployment 1613 doesn't contain any rules. But if i unzip the bar file I can see .drl and and bpmn.xml file that only I deployed. And I have deployed jar file of model class in web/inf folder. I'm noe getting why it is not getting drl file.

Comment: are you sure that your DRL file is valid? do you have a unit test checking that?

Comment: yeah in eclipse when i ran the junit test it is working

Comment: Can you create a small reproducer and push it to github? I bet that is eclipse tricking you